# Number of tourist paths

Tags: catalan-numbers

Please, would someone give me a hint to this exercise?

Tourist path is refracted line from point (0,0) to (2n,0), created from 2n line segments, where every line segment is determined by vector (1,1) or (1,-1). Show that number of paths, which doesn't go under axis x, is same as number of paths which only just one line segment goes under the axis x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think that your last bit of sentence "which only just **one** line segment goes under the axis x" should be "which only just **two** line segment goes under the axis x".

Second, just note that if there are only two segments under axis x (say that the crossings of the axis occur at $x=L$ and $x=L+2$ with $L<2n$), you are left with two similar problems :

- "On the left", from $x=0$ to $x=L$, how many paths can you find that do not cross the axis ?
- "On the right", from $x=L+2$ to $x=2n$ how many paths can you find that do not cross the axis ?

Now, you should also ask yourself how many $L$ exist such that only two segments go under the axis.

So basically, the whole problem reduces to know how many paths exist that never cross the axis.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake that I wasn't specific. Thank you.